# Why are web components light DOM style "leaking" as text to the DOM in certain cases while styling still functions?

Tags: html, css, web-component

While learning web components, I came across a peculiar case of CSS style "leaking" to the DOM apparently as a text node while it seems to work still. See in the provided image as pointed by the yellow arrow on how the CSS text shows up in the DOM as a text node. This can be tested by altering the CSS selector between `*` (leaks) and `div` (does not leak).

How could this be explained? See code and image and if you want to try out quickly, there's a pen at https://codepen.io/veksi/pen/WNvMOYg where you can switch the selector (tested with Firefox and Chrome).

```
<this-test>
  <div>
    <p>Some test text in div.</p>
    <p>Some more some text in div.</p>
    <p>And even more some text in div.</p>
  </div>

  <section>
    <p>Some test text in section.</p>
    <p>Some more some text in section.</p>
    <p>And even more some text in section.</p>
  </section>
</this-test>

const template = document.createElement('template');

template.innerHTML = `
  <style>
    /* Why does changing the following selector to
           this-test > *
       i.e. to the asterisk to match all elements, "leak" out while otherwise seem to work? */
    this-test > div {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      color: hotpink;
    }

    p {
      background: #abcabc;
      padding: 1rem;
      border: 0;
      font-size: 1.5rem;
    }
  </style>  
`;

class ThisTest extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();

    //Note that shadow root is not used.
    this.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));       
  }  
}

window.customElements.define('this-test', ThisTest);
```

[image: CSS style text leaking to the DOM as text node as indicated by a yellow arrow.]

Comment: You need to explain more specifically what you mean by "leaking."  Your image doesn't sufficiently convey the concept.

Comment: Thaks. Tried to explain in more clear terms.

Comment: I've been working with web components as my main daily subject for 2 years now, and I have no clue what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not related to Custom Elements/Web Components

All DOM elements have a `display:` setting

**By default <title> , <script> and <style> tags have `display:none`**

When you use `* {display:block}` (or any setting)
the **contents** of those normally hidden elements are now displayed in the page

It is a fun way to display contents of **inline** STYLE and SCRIPT tags:

```html
<title desc=" Title of this HTML document">Hello DOM World!</title>
<script desc=" Logs text to the DEV console">console.log("Hello from SCRIPT")</script>
<style>
  *{
    display:block;
    font-size:9px;
    color:red;
  }
  title,
  script{
    font-size:2em;
    color:blue;
  }
  *:hover:after{
    display:inline;
    content:attr(desc);
    color:green;
  }
</style>
```

The first red style block is what SO injects in the snippet

Comment: The problem is that flexbox applies to the style tag. Check in debugger to see (e.g. FF shows nicely). Feel free to make this and I accept it as the answer. :)

Comment: It is "normal" DOM behaviour